# Is there an implementation of the minimal viable plasma concept as proposed by Vitalik Buterin

Tags: solidity, plasma

Vitalik Buterin has proposed a minimal viable plasma concept at

https://ethresear.ch/t/minimal-viable-plasma/426

**[Q]**: is there a running implementation of this concept available?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are three implementations

1. https://github.com/omisego/plasma-mvp
2. https://github.com/mrsmkl/truebit-plasma
3. https://github.com/loomnetwork/plasma-cash

Especially the following root chain Solidity contracts help a lot to better understand the concept.

- https://github.com/omisego/plasma-mvp/blob/master/plasma/root_chain/contracts/RootChain/RootChain.sol
- https://github.com/mrsmkl/truebit-plasma/blob/master/plasma.sol
- https://github.com/loomnetwork/plasma-cash/blob/master/server/contracts/Core/RootChain.sol

Additionally:

- [a good YT video explaining how it works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jTc_2tyT_lY)
- [The Plasma World Map](https://ethresear.ch/t/plasma-world-map-the-hitchhiker-s-guide-to-the-plasma/4333) - designed to guide anyone traveling on a long journey to plasma